# Is the pullback of two covering spaces $\tilde X$ and $\hat X$ a covering space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose we have two covering spaces $p:\tilde X \rightarrow X$ and $q:\hat X \rightarrow X$ of the same space. Is the pullback $\tilde X \times_X \hat X$ also a covering space of $X$? If yes, what would be a proof?

Comment: It depends on your conventions. If you require covering spaces to be connected, then no. (But you shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

being just a fiber bundle with discrete fibers - yes. Look at some proof of pullbacks of fiber bundles, which are used more often in general than in basic covering space theory. But good question!

Comment: I thought it would be necessary to have finite fibres? At least only in this case I know a proof where the composition of two covering maps is again a covering map...

Comment: No discrete is also alright. If they were finite our beloved covering map $\mathbb R \to S^1$ would not be a covering.

Comment: Yes, obviously. But I meant that finiteness as a necessary condition for the statement about compositions, not as a general property of fibres.